# Watch and trace execution of a program with python

Tags: python

I want to run a external program within my python script and I want to pop up a message to user when he/she reached the specific stage of the program.
Is there a way to watch actions of the user?

Comment: What stage would that be? Could you elaborate?

Comment: For example, there is a installation and user click on several "next" and I want to pop up a message after the third "next".
The problem is that the installation is out of my code's control. I want it under my control.

Comment: Look into the source for the profiler (in `profile`) or pdb, either one might give you some hints on how to proceed. it's probably possible, but not necessarily simple.